# How do I run Spark jobs concurrently in the same AWS EMR cluster ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, livy

Is it possible to submit and run Spark jobs concurrently in the same AWS EMR cluster ? If yes then could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 4):

You should use the tag `--deploy-mode cluster` that will allow you to deploy multiple executions to your cluster. That will make yarn handle the resources and the queues for you.

The full example:

```
spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \  # can be client for client mode
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

More details [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html).

Comment: Hello Thiago could you please let me knowthe equivalent command for doing the same in aws

Comment: The reason I ask this is because the spark-submit is always treated as a step in EMR which is executed sequentially. Please read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently, EMR doesn't support running multiple steps in parallel. As far as I know such experimental feature is already implemented but not released due to some issues.